# how to make div tag appear directly to the right of the preceding div tag

Tags: html, css, position

I have the following code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        .left {
            width: 30px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .right {
            background-color: red;
            width: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left">Text</div>
    <div class="right">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The red div appears directly underneath the green div, but I want to make it so that the red div is directly to the right of the green div - how should I do this? Adding a float: right css property does not work as it goes to the other side of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: green;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="left">Text</div>
    <div class="right">Text</div>
```

You have to use floats to achieve this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        .left {
            float: left;
            width: 30px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
            background-color: red;
            width: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left">Text</div>
    <div class="right">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```